# Read a json file kept in different drive to that of source code react with typescript

Tags: json, frontend, react-typescript

Read a json file which is kept in different drive from the source code, for example if the source code is in C drive, then the json file which has to be read is in D drive

Comment: you have to use the absolute path to specify the drive

Comment: can't use, there is a problem, if you have any sample or example please share the link

Comment: Can you share your code? And which operating system you are using

Comment: windows, with fetch method i'm giving absolute path , please share any example link